# SEVERE: Exception starting filter struts2 java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

Tags: java, apache, hibernate, jsp, struts2

I am trying to integrate struts with hibernate.
This is the error stack trace.

```
Apr 3, 2014 7:56:10 PM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.TextParser)
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.fs.DefaultFileManagerFactory).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
Apr 3, 2014 7:56:11 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext filterStart
SEVERE: Exception starting filter struts2
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory.buildBean(ObjectFactory.java:151)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory.buildBean(ObjectFactory.java:182)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory.buildBean(ObjectFactory.java:171)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.factory.DefaultInterceptorFactory.buildInterceptor(DefaultInterceptorFactory.java:42)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory.buildInterceptor(ObjectFactory.java:202)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.InterceptorBuilder.constructInterceptorReference(InterceptorBuilder.java:70)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.lookupInterceptorReference(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:1110)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.loadInterceptorStack(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:928)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.loadInterceptorStacks(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:941)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.loadInterceptors(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:964)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.addPackage(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:533)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.loadPackages(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:292)
    at org.apache.struts2.config.StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.loadPackages(StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.java:112)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reloadContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:258)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:67)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:445)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:489)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.InitOperations.initDispatcher(InitOperations.java:74)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.init(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:57)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:295)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.setFilterDef(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:424)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:115)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4072)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4726)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: No Hibernate Validator class found (neither 3.x nor 4.x)
    at com.googlecode.s2hibernate.struts2.plugin.s2hibernatevalidator.interceptor.HibernateValidatorInterceptor.configValidator(HibernateValidatorInterceptor.java:51)
    at com.googlecode.s2hibernate.struts2.plugin.s2hibernatevalidator.interceptor.HibernateValidatorInterceptor.<clinit>(HibernateValidatorInterceptor.java:24)
    ... 43 more
Apr 3, 2014 7:56:11 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Error filterStart
Apr 3, 2014 7:56:11 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Context [/StrutsLoginApp] startup failed due to previous errors
log4j:ERROR LogMananger.repositorySelector was null likely due to error in class reloading, using NOPLoggerRepository.
Apr 3, 2014 7:56:12 PM com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider info
INFO: Parsing configuration file [struts-default.xml]
Apr 3, 2014 7:56:12 PM com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider info
INFO: Unable to locate configuration files of the name struts-plugin.xml, skipping
Apr 3, 2014 7:56:12 PM com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider info
INFO: Parsing configuration file [struts-plugin.xml]
Apr 3, 2014 7:56:12 PM com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider info
INFO: Parsing configuration file [struts.xml]
Apr 3, 2014 7:56:12 PM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory)
Apr 3, 2014 7:56:12 PM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.factory.ActionFactory)
Apr 3, 2014 7:56:12 PM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.factory.ResultFactory)
Apr 3, 2014 7:56:12 PM org.apache.struts2.config.AbstractBeanSelectionProvider info
```

While trying to run the application i am getting the above errors. Please let me know the what would be the problem.

Here is the list of jar files

```
struts2-core-2.3.16.1.jar
xwork-core-2.3.16.1.jar
ognl-3.0.6.jar
commons-fileupload-1.3.1.jar
commons-io-2.2.jar
commons-logging-1.1.3.jar
commons-logging-api-1.1.jar
freemarker-2.3.19.jar
javassist-3.11.0.GA.jar
commons-lang-2.4.jar
commons-lang3-3.1.jar
ognl-3.0.6.jar
antlr-2.7.7.jar
dom4j-1.6.1.jar
hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.4.Final.jar
hibernate-core-4.3.4.Final.jar
hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar
hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.4.Final.jar
hibernate-osgi-4.3.4.Final.jar
org.osgi.compendium-4.3.1.jar
org.osgi.core-4.3.1.jar
jandex-1.1.0.Final.jar
jboss-logging-3.1.3.GA.jar
jboss-logging-annotations-1.2.0.Beta1.jar
hibernate-release-api_1.2_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar
commons-collections-3.1.jar
struts2-convention-plugin-2.3.16.1.jar
struts2-fullhibernatecore-plugin-2.2.2-GA.jar
postgresql-9.3-1101.jdbc4.jar
slf4j-api-1.5.8.jar
slf4j-log4j12-1.5.8.jar
log4j-1.2.15.jar
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you want struts2-fullhibernatecore-plugin-2.2.2-GA.jar? If you do want that, then you'll also need to get the Hibernate [validator](http://hibernate.org/validator/). If you don't want that, then just take that jar out.

Comment: its required to add struts2-fullhibernatecore-plugin-2.2.2-GA.jar to integrate struts2 with hibernate right ?

Comment: Nope. I've used Struts and Hibernate together extensively for at least the last 6 years (more if you include Struts 1) and have yet to even see that jar until now. I suppose you need it if you want to utilize some service it provides, but just straight Hibernate / Struts usage, no need. Take it out. See what happens!